# Android Studio: No Menu Icon Showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm new to Android Studio and I am trying to create a note app. However, I can't seem to interact with my action bar at all.

I am using the latest version of Android Studio. I was looking some tutorials of Android Studio, videos of one year ago, and in the videos, the app emulator showed 3 dots (the settings icon) on the top-right corner of the action bar. However, mine doesn't create it. It doesn't create any menu icon. In fact, I do NOT have a menu sub-folder on my RES folder, and my MainActivity.java does NOT have the onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected methods that should be created by default.

Any way I can fix this? How can I add a simple icon my action bar?

Thank you

Comment: Check this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Try all the different templates in the New Project menu. Maybe some of them works for you.. And good luck :/

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add these methods manually by clicking `CTRL+O` (shortcut for override methods) and choose these two methods from the list.

You can also write them from scratch or copy-paste them from somewhere.

**EDIT:**

Try all the different templates in the New Project menu. Maybe some of them works for you. And good luck. This appears to be some weird bug.

Comment: Yes I know I can do that, but what I am saying is that I don't get any menu interface when I create a new app. I don't have the Menu folder in Res either, and I have no clue how I can add a simple "+" icon to my action bar.

Comment: Well when creating a new project, choose it with a template called "Blank Activity". You'll get a floating action button and a menu :)

Comment: That's what I always do but I don't get any floating action button :(. I really don't know what I'm doing here. i get the default action bar, but I don't have any icon and/or button on it

Comment: Goddamn it. What version of Android Studio do you have? I got 1.5.1 (Click on Help -> About).

Comment: I told you, the latest one. 2.1

Comment: I do know on older versions, Android Studio DOES add what I need. I do not know why on the newest one it doesn't anymore.

Comment: Check in your SDK Manager, what Android versions you have installed.

Comment: API 21 and above. (Android 5.0 and above)

Comment: I have 4.0.3 API 15 and above. I've no idea why you're facing these issues. What happens when you manually implement these two methods? Do the 3 dots appear?

Comment: No, nothing happens. The methods are there but my layout is still the same. :/ I'm dying here because I need to finish this app by tomorrow.

Comment: Well I wish I knew how to help you, I really do. The lesson you've learned is **Do not delay it till the last moment!** :D

Comment: Well I was given this homework yesterday so it's not till the last moment... Thanks though, I guess.